# How maintain order in postgresql result from two different schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement. I need to take count of same tables from two different schema. The required output should be like (see screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWYqw.png))

| schema | table_name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sch1 | table1 | 1000 |
| sch2 | table1 | 500 |
| sch1 | table2 | 3000 |
| sch2 | table2 | 1000 |

this is to take count difference of table from schema1 and schema2. so i get an output in above fashion  i can use LAG() or LEAD function. Please help

I tried many ways. But all result I'm getting related to group by usage only which will not maintain the expected fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the list of tables cannot be hard-coded (say you need to iterate on `information_schema.tables`), [**dynamic SQL**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) must be used. For each table, a query must be generated, and then executed in a second step.

You may use this function to generate and execute the row count of a given table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION row_count(schema_name text, table_name text)
 RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
 cnt bigint;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('select count(*) from %I.%I',
              schema_name, table_name)
    INTO cnt;
   RETURN cnt;
END
$function$
```

Then use it in the following query to get in a single result set all row counts of tables that exist with the same name in multiple schemas:

```
WITH list(s,t) as (select table_schema, table_name
  from information_schema.tables
  where table_type='BASE TABLE'
    and table_schema in ('schema1', 'schema2')
)
SELECT l1.s, l1.t, row_count(l1.s, l1.t)
  FROM list l1 JOIN list l2 ON l1.t=l2.t and l1.s<>l2.s;
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel.This helped me start off.I made some changes in it as per the requirement.It works

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most straightforward way of doing this is by making `UNION ALL` of 4 subqueries, each retrieving your counts from your four tables.

```
SELECT 'sch1' AS schema, 'table1' AS tablename, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM sch1.table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sch2',           'table1',              COUNT(*)        FROM sch2.table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sch1',           'table2',              COUNT(*)        FROM sch1.table2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sch2',           'table2',              COUNT(*)        FROM sch2.table2
```

Comment: No.This not the expected as here its hard coding. We are taking those from information schema .and table row count using quert_xml. Now we have to take the difference of table row count between the schema

Comment: If you want the counts, you need to access the actual tables. And if you have to access the actual tables, it's not worth to access the information_schema table as well, as that would result into extra unnecessary join operations. Regarding the difference, you're not giving details in your post relatively to what are the elements you're making difference on.